Conditional extinction probabilities; a problem
I am studying the following problem in An Intermediate Course in Probability by Gut:

The growth dynamics of pollen cells can be modeled by binary splitting as follows: After one unit of time, a cell either splits into two or dies. The new cells develop according to the same law independently of each other. The probabilities of dying and splitting are 0.46 and 0.54, respectively.
(a) Determine the maximal initial size of the population in order for the probability of extinction to be at least 0.3.
(b) What is the probability that the population is extinct after two generations if the initial population is the maximal number obtained in (a)?

I am unsure how to approach both (a) and (b). The assumption of the processes I am studying (Galton-Watson processes) is that $X(0)=1$, i.e. the population starts with one single ancestor. Then $X(1)$ denotes the number of children obtained by the ancestor. The offspring probability is $p$. I know the extinction probability $\eta$ is the smallest nonnegative root to $t=g(t)$, where $g(t)=q+pt^2$ (the PGF of the offspring random variable), so $\eta=q/p<1$ (here $q=1-p$). So $\eta$ is known, but how can there be an initial population bigger than $1$? I don't think I understand part (a). The answer to (a) is 7.
Regarding (b), if $q_n=P(X(n)=0)$, then I know that $q_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_kq_{n-1}^k$ holds (this identity is proved in e.g. Durrett's book). So I can compute $q_n=P(X(n)=0)$ for any $n\geq 1$, but I don't think this is the probability they are after. The answer to (b) is 0.0206.
Any help is appreciated.

If the initial population consists of $N$ cells, and the probability that a single cell's "bloodline" eventually ends is $p$, then the probability that the entire population eventually goes extinct is simply $p^N$, by independence. Therefore, let's focus our attention on a single cell.
The probability $p$ can be found by defining it recursively. The cell can either die in the first stage with probability $0.46$, or it can split and yield two offspring with probability $0.54$. In the former case, the probability of eventual extinction is obviously $1$ (there are no offspring to begin with). In the latter case, since the offspring have statistical properties identical to the parent (and independent from others), the probability of eventual extinction is $p^2$. So, we have the equation
$$p = 0.46 + 0.54 p^2 \implies 0.54 p^2 - p + 0.46 = 0$$
which has solutions $p = 1$ (extraneous) and $p = \frac{23}{27}$. We are therefore looking for the maximum $N$ such that
$$\left( \frac{23}{27} \right)^N \le 0.3 \implies N \le \frac{\ln 0.3}{\ln \frac{23}{27}} \approx 7.5088$$
which is $\boxed{N = 7}$.
The wording for part (b) is rather ambiguous (and could in fact be interpreted in two completely contrasting ways!). I will take it to mean

What is the probability that the population goes extinct at or before $2$ generations?

As you have pointed out, it is easy to compute the probability that a cell's bloodline goes extinct at or prior to a particular generation. Since the only possibilities are zero offspring (with probability $0.46$) or two offspring (with probability $0.54$), this is given by
$$\begin{cases}
u_k = 0.46 + 0.54 u_{k - 1}^2 \\ 
u_0 = 0
\end{cases}$$
Computing, we have $u_1 = 0.46$ and $u_2 \approx 0.5743$. But this is for a single cell. For the entire population to go extinct at or before $2$ generations, the probability is
$$u_2^N \approx (0.5743)^7 \approx \boxed{0.02060}$$
as desired.
